# Checkbox always returns true when it is unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have nested `Gridview` and the last `Gridview` has `Checkbox`.

the condition in checking the `Checkbox` whether it is checked or unchecked

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
       GridView GridView2= gvr.FindControl("GridView2") as GridView;
       foreach (GridViewRow gvr2 in GridView2.Rows)
       {
           GridView GridView3= gvr2.FindControl("GridView3") as GridView;
           foreach (GridViewRow gvr3 in GridView3.Rows)
           {
               if(((CheckBox)gvr3.FindControl("chk1")).Checked)
               {
                    string txt = txtKeyboard.text;
               }
           }
       }
}
```

even though it is unchecked it will go though the condition

Comment: post more code for identifying problem

Comment: are you sure you are referencing the right gridrow and right checkbox?  there is no reason why that wont work unless you are checking it in code somewhere else before this loop gets executed or you are referencing the wrong checkbox.

Comment: Yes Im definitely sure that i am referencing the right checkbox from the gridview

Comment: Please post the whole class. We can't help you if you don't do that.

Comment: Where did you wrote this code? I mean which event ?

Comment: I am constructing it to get the list of keyboard.

`KeyboardToADD();`

I am getting all the keyboard ID as a datatable

Answer (score 1):

```
if(((CheckBox)gvr3.FindControl("chk1")).Checked)
{
     string txt = txtKeyboard.text;
}
```

instead of above code just try once

```
  CheckBox chk1 = gvr3.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
  if(chk1.checked==true)
  {
      string txt = txtKeyboard.text;
  }
```

here you need to set cell value and control value inplace of `0`

Comment: Also returning the uncheck buttons to true

Comment: @Registered_User012345 i clearey mentioned here that you need to set value of cells(order of checkbox from starting of Gridview3) and control in place of 0

Comment: Sorry I double check the control placement and corrected it.
The code also returning true even though the checkboxs are unchecked

Comment: @Registered_User012345 PLEASE PUT YOUR ASPX CODE OR COME TO [THIS ROOM](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/dont-rely-on-us)

Answer (score 0):

How you bind data to "GridView2" control? if you called some methods like "GridView2_DataBind" , after postback data has be processed, the state of girdview will be reset.

for example,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
          if (!this.IsPostBack){ 
              GridView2_DataBind() // you shouldn't call databind method when postback
          }
 }
```

Comment: Nope, Im not binding the grids in postback