# CheckBox reverts to checked after being unchecked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, visual-studio-2013

I have a ASP.Net web page that includes a nested GridView. Within the nested GridView is a template field with a CheckBox. This AutoPostBack is set to True in order to fire the CheckedChanged event. When you click a CheckBox to change it from the checked to unchecked state it reverts back to being checked.

I need to know what CheckBox is unchecked so that I can remove it from my DataTable that includes currently selected items.

Download entire project .zip [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq97e5ybl0hgrhw/CNUScheduleCreation.zip?dl=0)

The code for this problem is in the CreateSchedule.aspx file in the Views folder.

Here is the ASP.Net for the GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="25px" Width="250px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <RowStyle Height="25px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName"  HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="CourseName" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" height="25px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSections" runat="server" Style="display: none"> 
                        <!-- Table inside the table -->
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CRN" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="25px" HorizontalAlign="left"/>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtrl" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedClicked" AutoPostBack="True"  />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Days" SortExpression="Days" >
                                    <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" SortExpression="Time" >
                                    <ItemStyle Width="90px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>

                        <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="white" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CRN], [Days], [Time] FROM [ScheduleOfClasses] WHERE ([Course] = ?)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name=" Course" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#04488A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#04488A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#04488A" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="white" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my `Page_Load` sub for this page. Essentially if it is not a post back it creates a new DataTable/Xml file and overwrites. If it is a post back (ie. when CheckBox is clicked) it should be checking for any rows that are no longer checked and removing it from the DataTable. I cannot test the logic of it because it gets rechecked.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Me.SetDataSource("ACCT")

        ' Create a new DataTable. 
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("CourseSelection")

        ' Declare variables for DataColumn and DataRow objects. 
        Dim column As DataColumn

        ' Create new DataColumn, set DataType, ColumnName  
        ' and add to DataTable.    
        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        column.ColumnName = "crn"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.ReadOnly = True
        column.Unique = True '- same CRN does not conflict

        ' Add the Column to the DataColumnCollection.
        table.Columns.Add(column)

        ' Create course column.
        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "course"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.ReadOnly = False
        column.Unique = False

        ' Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column)

        ' Create instructor column.
        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "instructor"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.ReadOnly = False
        column.Unique = False

        ' Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column)

        ' Create course time column.
        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "coursetime"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.ReadOnly = False
        column.Unique = False

        ' Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column)

        ' Create course day column.
        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "courseday"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.ReadOnly = False
        column.Unique = False

        ' Add the column to the table.
        table.Columns.Add(column)

        ' Make the ID column the primary key column, taken out to avoid conflict of unique key
        Dim PrimaryKeyColumns(0) As DataColumn
        PrimaryKeyColumns(0) = table.Columns("crn")
        table.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns

        Dim dsXML As New DataSet("CourseSelections")
        dsXML.Merge(table)
        dsXML.WriteXml("c:\temp\dt.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        ' Else statement to be worked on
    Else
        Dim nestedCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim subject As String
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ' XML File Directory
        ds.ReadXml("c:\temp\dt.xml")

        Dim table As New DataTable
        table = ds.Tables("CourseSelection")

        Dim CheckedCRNs As New ArrayList
        subject = Left(GridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).ToString(), 4)
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim NestedGridView As GridView = GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).FindControl("GridView2")
            nestedCounter = 0
            For Each r As GridViewRow In NestedGridView.Rows
                If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(r.Cells(0).FindControl("chkCtrl"), CheckBox)
                    If chkRow.Checked Then
                        CheckedCRNs.Add(NestedGridView.DataKeys(nestedCounter).Value.ToString())
                    End If
                End If
                nestedCounter = nestedCounter + 1
            Next
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Next
        Dim foundRows() As DataRow
        If Not table.Select("course like '" & subject & "*'").Length = CheckedCRNs.Count Then
            foundRows = table.Select("course like '" & subject & "*'")
            For i = 0 To foundRows.GetUpperBound(0)
                If Not CheckedCRNs.Contains(foundRows(i)(0)) Then
                    table.Rows(i).Delete()
                End If
            Next i
            Dim dsXML As New DataSet("CourseSelections")
            dsXML.Merge(table)
            dsXML.WriteXml("c:\temp\dt.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

CheckedClicked sub:

```
    Protected Sub CheckedClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' Variables to be pulled from Database
    Dim Course As String = ""
    Dim CourseTime As String = ""
    Dim CourseDay As String = ""
    Dim Instructor As String = ""
    ' Variables used for position of columns and rows
    Dim crn As Integer
    Dim nestedCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ' Color variables
    Dim colorOfClass As String = ""
    colorOfClass = getColorOfClasses(colorPosition)


    ' XML File Directory
    ds.ReadXml("c:\temp\dt.xml")

    Dim table As New DataTable
    table = ds.Tables("CourseSelection")

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim NestedGridView As GridView = GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).FindControl("GridView2")
        nestedCounter = 0
        For Each r As GridViewRow In NestedGridView.Rows
            If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(r.Cells(0).FindControl("chkCtrl"), CheckBox)
                If chkRow.Checked Then
                    If table.Select("CRN='" & NestedGridView.DataKeys(nestedCounter).Value.ToString() & "'").Length = 0 Then
                        crn = NestedGridView.DataKeys(nestedCounter).Value.ToString()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            nestedCounter = nestedCounter + 1
        Next
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Try
        Using con
            con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString2").ConnectionString
            con.Open()
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Course, Time, Days, Instructor FROM ScheduleOfClasses WHERE CRN= " & crn
                Using oRDR As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    'Gets columns for each value
                    While (oRDR.Read)
                        Course = oRDR.GetValue(0)
                        CourseTime = oRDR.GetValue(1)
                        CourseDay = oRDR.GetValue(2)
                        Instructor = oRDR.GetValue(3)
                    End While
                End Using
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    Dim dRow As DataRow

    dRow = table.NewRow()
    dRow("crn") = CInt(crn)
    dRow("course") = Course
    dRow("instructor") = Instructor
    dRow("coursetime") = CourseTime
    dRow("CourseDay") = CourseDay
    table.Rows.Add(dRow)
    arrayOfCRNs.Add(crn)

    Dim NewDs As New DataSet("CourseSelections")

    NewDs.Merge(table)
    NewDs.WriteXml("c:\temp\dt.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

    Dim cDay As String = ""   'Current day when looping through class days
    Dim cCol As Integer = 0   'Current column that is set based on the cDay
    Dim StartRow As Integer   'Row in the table that the class starts
    Dim ClassLength As Integer = 0   'Number of rows in the table to be colored in based on the length of the class
    Dim StartHours As String = Mid(CourseTime, 3, 2)   'The hour of the day that the class starts 




    Select Case StartHours
        Case "00"   'When the class starts on the hour, StartRow is calculated to the correlated hour
            StartRow = (CInt(Left(CourseTime, 2)) - 8) * 4
        Case "30"   'When the class starts at the bottom of the hour, StartRow is calculated to the correlated _
            'hour plus 2 to account for thirty minutes
            StartRow = (CInt(Left(CourseTime, 2)) - 8) * 4 + 2
    End Select

    'Class length of a class is the total minutes divided by 15 minutes per hour, rounded down
    ClassLength = Math.Floor((CInt(Mid(CourseTime, 6, 4)) - CInt(Left(CourseTime, 4))) / 15)
    'Conversion from Class Length = 7, to 5 cells
    ClassLength = ClassLength - ((CInt(Mid(CourseTime, 6, 2)) - CInt(Left(CourseTime, 2))) * 2)

    'Number of course days as size of String, checking String for each day Monday-Friday 

    For n As Integer = 1 To CourseDay.Length
        cDay = Mid(CourseDay, n, 1)   'Set cDay to the nth day
        Select Case cDay
            Case "M"
                cCol = 0
            Case "T"
                cCol = 1
            Case "W"
                cCol = 2
            Case "R"
                cCol = 3
            Case "F"
                cCol = 4
        End Select

        Dim fillRowCounter As Integer = 1

        ' Populate the table with the correct data
        For cRow As Integer = StartRow To StartRow + ClassLength - 1

            'If the current row is divisible by 4 then add one; this is due to the row span of the first column
            If cRow Mod 4 = 0 Then cCol = cCol + 1
            schedule.Rows(cRow).Cells(cCol).BgColor = colorOfClass
            If fillRowCounter = 1 Then schedule.Rows(cRow).Cells(cCol).InnerText = CInt(crn)
            If fillRowCounter = 2 Then schedule.Rows(cRow).Cells(cCol).InnerText = Course
            If fillRowCounter = 3 Then schedule.Rows(cRow).Cells(cCol).InnerText = Instructor
            If fillRowCounter > 3 Then schedule.Rows(cRow).Cells(cCol).InnerText = ""
            If cRow Mod 4 = 0 Then cCol = cCol - 1
            fillRowCounter = fillRowCounter + 1

        Next cRow
    Next n
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my GridViews to data bind on `Page_Load` rather than having a SqlDataSource. However I am still having the same issue as before. Below is my sub that I call to initially bind the GridView.

```
    Protected Sub SetDataSource(Subject As String)
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString2").ConnectionString
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT [CourseName] FROM [Courses] WHERE ([SubjectID] = '" & Subject & "')"
    Dim DataKeyArray As String() = {"CourseName"}
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Try
        ' Connect to the database and run the query.
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

        ' Fill the DataSet.
        adapter.Fill(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' The connection failed. Display an error message.
        'Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database."
    End Try

    ' Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
    ' to the GridView control.
    If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataKeyNames = DataKeyArray
        GridView1.DataBind()
        ds.Dispose()
        ds.Clear()
    Else
        'Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database."
    End If



    Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim DataKeyArray2 As String() = {"CRN"}
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim NestedGridView As GridView = GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).FindControl("GridView2")
        Dim gView = GridView1
        queryString = "SELECT [CRN], [Days], [Time] FROM [ScheduleOfClasses] WHERE ([Course] = '" & GridView1.DataKeys(rowCounter).Value & "')"
        Try
            ' Connect to the database and run the query.
            Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

            ' Fill the DataSet.
            adapter.Fill(ds)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' The connection failed. Display an error message.
            'Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database."
        End Try

        ' Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
        ' to the GridView control.
        If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
            NestedGridView.DataSource = ds
            NestedGridView.DataKeyNames = DataKeyArray2
            NestedGridView.DataBind()
            ds.Dispose()
            ds.Clear()
        Else
            'Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database."
        End If
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2**

When debugging the `Page_Load` event after unchecking a box, the checkbox on the web page appears to be unchecked but `chkRow.Checked` has a value of true even though the checkbox appears unchecked on the web page. (chkRow is the checkbox that was being unchecked)

**UPDATE 3**

I have made somewhat of a breakthrough. I figured out that the problem with the checkboxes is that the nested gridview is located within a panel that collapses and expands using JavaScript. Essentially it is a bug in ASP.Net when a control is disable on `Page_Load` and then enabled later. I figured this out because my `GridView2` and `chkCtrl` are not able to be referenced in VB and therefore the `GridView2` is not initialized on `Page_Load`. I also figured it out by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523606/asp-net-checkbox-value-at-postback-is-wrong?lq=1). The solution mentions creating a hidden field and setting it to the value of the other checkbox but I am unsure of how to do that with my situation.

When I comment out the panel, the checkboxes uncheck as expected and ClickedChanged is fired. However, I need the collapsible panel because it is a lot of data with everything expanded. I was thinking that if I could initially load all of GridViews and then collapse them on `Page_Load` but I don't know how to do that either.

Here is the most up to date aspx for my GridView, this time including the code for my panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<%'Using plus and minus images to show drop down of classes'%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>

<%'Grid View Table'%>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="25px" Width="250px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <RowStyle Height="25px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName"  HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="CourseName" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" height="25px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSections" runat="server" Style="display: none">  
                        <!-- Table inside the table -->
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CRN" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemStyle Width="25px" HorizontalAlign="left"/>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtrl" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedClicked" AutoPostBack="True"  />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Days" SortExpression="Days" >
                                    <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" SortExpression="Time" >
                                    <ItemStyle Width="90px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>

                        <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="white" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CRN], [Days], [Time] FROM [ScheduleOfClasses] WHERE ([Course] = ?)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name=" Course" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </asp:Panel> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#04488A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#04488A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#04488A" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="white" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: In your `Page_Load` method, are you re-checking it?

Comment: No, I am only reading which rows are checked and comparing that to my DataTable.

Comment: What you do in CheckedClicked?

Comment: I am adding the information for the checked items to a table on next to the GridView. It seems that the CheckedClicked is only run when I initially click and item and not when I uncheck it. This is because CheckedClicked is only fired on CheckedChange and the CheckBox doesn't actually change when unchecked.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the CheckedClicked code?

Comment: I have added the CheckedClicked sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the GridView2 that contains the checkboxes is disabled on `Page_Load`. It is initially disabled because the gridview is nested inside a collapsible panel. I removed the panel and everything works perfectly.

I may post a different question to inquire about getting the collapsible panel to work.

Answer (score 0):

This strongly sounds like you forgot to check if the page is posted back or not in the `Page_Load` event where you bind the gridview data. Because of this, you are unintentionally re-binding gridview each time a checkbox is unchecked, which is why it reverts back to the original status (checked).

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
      //bind gridview
Else
      //other stuff
End
```

**UPDATE**

I think this is a `Postback` issue when gridviews are used with SqlDataSource. You may want to check the following resources, and may want to even change your data-binding method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18165161/1845408

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20520/Workaround-when-SQLDataSource-doesn-t-Maintain-Sel

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I do check if it is a post back. I added my `Page_Load` sub above. Also, I tried `GridView1.DataBind()` in my else statement and that made it so I can never check anything.

Comment: @JustinC11 where/when do you bind gridview?

Comment: The first line of my else statement.

Comment: @JustinC11 I am confused. else statement will be executed when checkbox is checked? you mean you are binding gridview when there is postback event?

Comment: I apologize. I misread your original post because I am not as familiar with C#. I forgot that ! means not. Will try it at the beginning of my `If Not IsPostBack' statement.

Comment: @JustinC11 just to make it clear: your gridview-binding code should be within this `If Not IsPostBack Then`

Comment: Yes, I tried putting it at the beginning of the `If Not IsPostBack Then` statement and it did not work. It also messed with the initial data set in the GridView after the initial load.

Comment: @JustinC11 exactly which line binds data to gridview?

Comment: I am actually using an SqlDataSource as the data source for the gridview. I added that code to the end of the ASP.Net for the gridview.

Comment: I think that could be it but I am not entirely sure if I understand their solution. Also, there are a few things that are different about my situation. 1. My gridview with the checkboxes is nested in another gridview which does not allow me to reference it directly in VB. 2. My event is not triggered by clicking a button but instead on CheckedChanged and since it doesn't change, I am unsure how to implement that. 3. My check boxes are not bound to anything--I don't know if that affects anything.

Comment: @JustinC11 I have an idea for testing. Can you disable `AutoPostBack` for the checkbox? Then, uncheck some checkboxes and, then add a asp.net button on the page, and click it. Let's see if the checkboxes will revert back to original?

Comment: When I click the button after unchecking an item it reverts back to being checked, just like it was with the `AutoPostBack=True`.

Comment: I see, now this makes sure the problem you are having. I think this issue has been around for a long time and some solutions are discussed: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20520/Workaround-when-SQLDataSource-doesn-t-Maintain-Sel

Comment: @JustinC11 please see my update, I guess you may need to implement a different data-binding methodology as discussed in the shared resources.

Comment: I think I am having the same issue as with the previous link. I am not using a button so I do not have an event that I can set the ViewState command. Also, I am not changing my data source in any way; all that is changing is the unbound checkbox. Do you think it will be fixed if I got rid of the SqlDataSource all together and set the data source on `Page_Load` instead?

Comment: @JustinC11 I am VERY positive about that but of course make a copy of your project first! Please keep posted.

Comment: I am working on switching over to binding my gridviews in VB and I am having trouble figuring out how to set the data source of the nested gridview. The nested gridview data source is dependent on the value in the parent gridview. I am unsure how to reference the parent value. Here is how I did it with my sql datasource on rowdatabound of GridView1: `If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim s As SqlDataSource = CType(e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource2"), SqlDataSource)
            s.SelectParameters(0).DefaultValue = e.Row.Cells(0).Text
        End If`

Comment: @JustinC11 you should use datakeyname for this purpose. With datakeyname you can attach the identifier to each row, and read back. I won't be available for a while but i am sure you can find many resources for this.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I used to set the data source of my GridView but I am still having the same issue with the checkboxes not unchecking.

Comment: @JustinC11 I do not see ` If Not IsPostBack Then` in your new code?

Comment: That new code is called from the `Page_Load` in the `If Not IsPostBack` statement.

Comment: @JustinC11 can you include that part as well?

Comment: I actually updated it already in place of the old `Page_Load` section of my question.

Comment: @JustinC11 can you pust break point to this line `GridView1.DataSource = ds` and see if the program pauses in this break when checkbox is clicked? Normally, it should stop once at the beginning.

Comment: It only stops there when the page is initially loaded. This is because it is a post back anytime I click a checkbox. I don't know if this helps any but when I am debugging the `Page_Load` event after I uncheck a box, the checkbox on the web page appears to be unchecked but the `chkRow.Checked` has a value of true even though I just unchecked that box.

Answer (score 0):

Use **OnChange** instead of **OnCheckedChanged**.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtrl" runat="server" OnChange="CheckedClicked" AutoPostBack="True"  />
```

Comment: It does not work because the `CheckedClicked` event is never fired because the CheckBox reverts back to checked (ie. there was no change). `Page_Load` runs when I check or uncheck something but CheckedClicked only runs when initially check an item.

Comment: Are you sure the CheckedClicked event is never fired after you click the checkbox by above code??

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It is only fired when I initially check an item, but not when I uncheck.

Comment: Could you put the download link of your project and db?

Comment: Added the download link. It is set up now with the code I had prior to changing to what you posted. The web page that this problem deals with is the CreateSchedule.aspx file in the Views folder.

Comment: OK,I will download it and try to find the issue out.

Comment: I tried changing it to `OnChange` but that did not fix my problem. It also caused the `CheckedClicked` event to not run at all.

Comment: Like your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243915/checkbox-always-returns-true-when-it-is-unchecked

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the collapsible panel to to not do it with javascript.  Use an ImageButton and a Panel surrounding the inner Gridview.  This keeps the ViewState in sync with what is actually happening.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ExpandButton" runat="server" OnClick="ExpandButton_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.png" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Put the panel inside the last column of the outer GridView, after any items.  In my case this was Cell[5], after some other buttons. Note this panel closes the cell and row of the outer Gridview and inserts a new row and starts a new cell for the inner GridView, spanning all columns.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Key Options" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center bg-info">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="AssignButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" Text="Assign Keys" Enabled="false" />
        <asp:Button ID="RecallButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" Text="Recall Key" Enabled="false" />

        <asp:Panel ID="KeysPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
            </td></tr><tr>
                <td colspan="999">
                    <asp:GridView ID="KeysGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped" 
                        EmptyDataText="No assignments have been made.">
                        <Columns>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The ExpandButton postback looks like this:

```
protected void ExpandButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow myRow = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    ImageButton expandBtn = sender as ImageButton;
    if (expandBtn.ImageUrl == "~/Images/plus.png")
    {
        expandBtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/minus.png";
        Panel pnl = myRow.Cells[5].Controls[0].FindControl("KeysPanel") as Panel;
        pnl.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        expandBtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/plus.png";
        Panel pnl = myRow.Cells[5].Controls[0].FindControl("KeysPanel") as Panel;
        pnl.Visible = false;
    }
}
```